# JOOQ interpreting JSONB as JSON when generating from script

Tags: postgresql, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'm using JOOQ with Postgresql, where I have a few columns of the JSONB type. Using the JOOQ code generator directly on the database itself (using org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase) works just fine, all generated classes use the JSONB type.

However, when switching to code generation via SQL scripts (using org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase as described here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl), the code generator converts all JSONB columns to JSON types.

How do I get the code generator to keep JSONB types?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the H2 database used by the DDL generator can only report the JSON type, and [forcing the type](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-matching/) solves my problem:

```
<forcedType>
  <name>JSONB</name>
  <includeTypes>JSON</includeTypes>
</forcedType>
```